# Replacing content of divs

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am trying to replace content in a div after it has been saved to the db without reloading the page. When I click the save buttons the edit window disappears however the post wont get updated until I reload the page. Each post is build by following template and there are multiple posts.

```
var formatPost = function(d) {
        var s = '';
        s = '<div class="postWrapper" data-id="' + d.post_id + '"><h2 class="postHeading">' + d.title + '</h2>';
        s += '<div class="postBody"> <p>' + d.body  + '</p> </div>';
        s += '<p> Posted on: ' + d.date + '</p>';  
        s += '<div class="btn editButton">Edit Post</div>'
        s += '<div class="btn deleteButton">Delete</div>';          
        s += '</div>'

        return s;
    };
```

The following function is run when the edit button is pressed

```
function(data) {
         var editableText = '<div class="editPostContainer" data-id="' + data.post_id + '">'
            editableText += '<input type="text" class="editPostHeader" value="' + data.title + '">';
            editableText += '<textarea class="editPostText">' + data.body + '</textarea>';
            editableText += '<div class="btn saveEditButton">Save</div>';
            editableText += '<div class="btn cancelButton">Cancel</div>';                
            editableText += '</div>';

            $(self).parent().append(editableText);
        }
```

When I click the save button following code is run

```
 $.post(settings.server, {
                saveID: $(this).parent().data('id'),
                title: $('.editPostHeader').val(),
                body: $('.editPostText').val()
            }, function(data){

                $(this).parent().siblings('.postHeading').text(data.title);
                $(this).parent().siblings('.postBody').text(data.body);

            });
```

And finaly the PHP that deals with the DB during this.

```
function save_post($id, $title, $body)
{
    global $link;

    $sql = "UPDATE post SET title= '$title',body= '$body' WHERE post_id= $id";

    mysqli_query($link, $sql);

    $sql = 'SELECT * FROM post WHERE id=' . $id;
    $result = mysqli_query($link, $sql);

    $saveResult = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

    print json_encode($saveResult);
}
```

Comment: What have you tried? Sounds like you just need to add code within your save handler to update the div content

Comment: Well I hoped that  `$(self).parent().siblings('.postHeading').text(data.title);` and `$(self).parent().siblings('.postBody').text(data.body);` would replace the existing text however that does not happen.

Comment: Ah, where is `self` declared as a variable? It would need to be in the correct context/scope for the callback to pick it up.  `$(self)` means nothing by itself...

Comment: I changed the `self` to `this` however I am still unsure if I am using the correct selector or not.

Comment: What is `this` supposed to refer to? The button clicked?

Comment: The text inside the `postHeading` div and `postBody` div

Comment: Huh? `$(this)` should be referring to a dom element

Comment: I am confused right now.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82111/discussion-between-ted-and-pavel-kaseljak).